# Why doesn't width_bucket always return equally sized buckets?

Tags: sql, db2

From what I understand, width_bucket function assigns values to buckets in an equi-width histogram. So I was hoping to see the bucket size to be consistent across partitions (except for the default bucket). However, I am unable to understand the behavior when I change the upper bound (2nd example).

```
--this works as expected
SELECT WIDTH_BUCKET(col,0,1000,10) AS bucket_no
, min(col) AS min_val
, max(col) AS max_max
, max(col) - min(col) AS width
FROM table
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY WIDTH_BUCKET(col,0,1000,10)
ORDER BY 1

BUCKET_NO|MIN_VAL|MAX_MAX|WIDTH|
---------+-------+-------+-----+
        1|      1|     99|   98|
        2|    100|    199|   99|
        3|    200|    299|   99|
        4|    300|    399|   99|
        5|    400|    499|   99|
        6|    500|    599|   99|
        7|    600|    699|   99|
        8|    700|    799|   99|
        9|    800|    899|   99|
       10|    900|    999|   99|
       11|   1000|  55786|54786|
```

in the second example, the number of partitions are not preserved nor are they of equal size.

```
--this one doesn't
SELECT WIDTH_BUCKET(col,0,100000,10) AS bucket_no
, min(col) AS min_val
, max(col) AS max_max
, max(col) - min(col) AS width
FROM table
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY WIDTH_BUCKET(col,0,100000,10)
ORDER BY 1

BUCKET_NO|MIN_VAL|MAX_MAX|WIDTH|
---------+-------+-------+-----+
        1|      1|   9971| 9970|
        2|  10014|  18020| 8006|
        3|  20246|  24007| 3761|
        4|  30070|  30070|    0|
        6|  55786|  55786|    0|
```

Comment: The reason behind the above is because of num_buckets value(in your case 10). That value decide the bucket width which is equal to `(bound2 - bound1) / num_bucket`. In second example it is 10000. Since in 1st bucket the max value that you are expecting is 10000 but the max value in that bucket is 9971 as `col` with max value 10000 doesn;t exist. Similarly in other buckets also, the expected max value as well as min value is not present in the `col` column. Hence the width that you are calculating is not coming in equal size.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I see behavior similar to my second scenario even for cases where boundaries are defined for all of the possible buckets. i have a date dimension with date id set to integer representation of date and the buckets do not work as i was expecting

Comment: Please provide the sample data on which you are running the query.

Comment: i have a date dimension with ids set as integer representation of dates in yyyymmdd format. for example, dt_id for "2021-01-01" is 20210101. This dimension table is populated with values starting from 2013-01-01 to 2025-12-31. There is also a record for unknown with dt_id set to 0. Now if I do a WIDTH_BUCKET(dt_id,20200101,20260101,20), I expect to see a bucket with id 0 (for all dates till 20200101), then 20 buckets each of equal width. But that is not what happens. I get back 9 non-consecutive buckets in total 0,1,4,7,8 etc. Please note that there is no missing boundary value

Comment: Can you create a sample table in dbfiddle and share the link here? Link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1

Comment: Thanks Nishant. 

Please use this link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=9906baa9332fe5d3cf1132dc880e4ee0

Comment: I think I know what is going on. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: So where were you going wrong?

Comment: i was stuck with the date values, and didn't realize that once they are converted to integers width_bucket will consider the entire range, a lot of which do not have associated entries in the dim table. For example, 20223131 will be a valid integer value in the range and will be considered by the width bucket but there won't be an entry in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [WIDTH_BUCKET scalar function](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-width-bucket) definition, the implementation should be something like below.
You can't expect equally sized buckets on non-consecutive input data as in your case.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION WIDTH_BUCKET_MY (EXPRESSION INT, BOUND1 INT, BOUND2 INT, NUM_BUCKETS INT)
RETURNS INT
CONTAINS SQL
DETERMINISTIC 
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
RETURN
  CASE 
    WHEN BOUND1 = BOUND2 THEN RAISE_ERROR ('70001', 'The same as SQLSTATE=2201G')::INT
    ELSE
      CASE
        WHEN EXPRESSION <  BOUND1 AND BOUND1 < BOUND2 OR EXPRESSION >  BOUND1 AND BOUND1 > BOUND2 THEN 0
        WHEN EXPRESSION >= BOUND2 AND BOUND1 < BOUND2 OR EXPRESSION <= BOUND2 AND BOUND1 > BOUND2 THEN NUM_BUCKETS + 1
        ELSE ABS ((EXPRESSION - BOUND1) * NUM_BUCKETS / (BOUND2 - BOUND1))::INT + 1
      END
  END
```